# How to create function to get data from WCF Rest then display to table

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, scope, wcf-rest

I have declare function to get WCF Rest the name is `service.js`, the url get Json data. Then I create another function to get data `entryCtrl.js` then show to html

*service.js*

```
(function (app) {
  app.service("CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService", function ($http) {
    this.getAllEntry = function () {
      return $http.get("http://localhost:51458/ServiceRequest.svc/GetAllRequest/");
    };
  });
})(angular.module('model'));
```

*entryCtrl.js*

```
(function (app) {
  'use strict';
  app.controller('entryCtrl', entryCtrl);
  entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function entryCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.pageClass = 'page-entry';
      $scope.GetAllRecords = function() {
          var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllEntry();
          promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.EntryData = pl.data },
                function (errorPl) {
                    $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
                });
      }
  }
})(angular.module('model'));
```

view *entry.html*

```
<table data-ng-controller="entryCtrl">
   <tbody data-ng-repeat="entry in EntryData">
     <tr>
       <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
       <td>{{entry.telpon}}</td>
       <td>{{entry.foobar}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't have any error, my data in table not show anything. What must I try to know the function it's work or not?

jush have warning `XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience`. I don't know what it is mean.

Comment: You have defined `function GetAllRecords() {`, so that is not a function on the `$scope` object. Instead of `$scope.GetAllRecords()` do just `GetAllRecords()`, or define the function on the scope object like `$scope.GetAllRecords = function() { //.. }`

Comment: please give me example. thank

Comment: Okey thank. It's work create function. But not display the table. And not have an error. What i'm worong? @devqon

Comment: Inspect your `pl.data` result and check if it is indeed an array with objects that have properties `name`, `telpon` and `foobar`, which your template expects

Comment: how to try the result? please give example

Comment: `promiseGet.then(function (pl) { console.log(pl.data); // ..`

Answer (score 1):

The function `GetAllRecords()` is not set to the `$scope`. You need to set `$scope.GetAllRecords = GetAllRecords` before the call to `$scope.GetAllRecords()`:

```
function entryCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pageClass = 'page-entry';
  $scope.GetAllRecords = function() {
      var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllEntry();
      promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.EntryData = pl.data },
            function (errorPl) {
                $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
            });
  }
  $scope.GetAllRecords();
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply call `GetAllRecords()` directly, since you don't seem to need it in the `$scope`:

```
function entryCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pageClass = 'page-entry';
  (function() {
      var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllEntry();
      promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.EntryData = pl.data },
            function (errorPl) {
                $log.error('Some Error in Getting Records.', errorPl);
            });
  })();
}
```

Comment: Are you mine like this? `entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', GetAllRecords]; function entryCtrl($scope) {..}; function GetAllRecords() { var promiseGet = CRUD_AngularJs_RESTService.getAllEntry(); .. }`